# cloudera installation: after install jdbc, mysql service failed

Tags: mysql, jdbc, installation, cloudera, cloudera-manager

i am new to Linux and Cloudera.

I am trying to install cloudera manager on CentOS. 
after I installed the mysql jdbc connector, I found the mysql service failed.
Here is what i got:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
# service mysqld start
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

can anybody give me some hints?

thanks a lot!

Comment: mysql version is 5.1.73, jdbc connector version is mysql-connector-java-5.1.36

Comment: i checked the mysqld.log, found some error message like:
150920 21:31:40 [ERROR] You need to use --log-bin to make --binlog-format work.
150920 21:31:40 [ERROR] Aborting